# swift facebook sdk logout function not working

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-sdk-4.0, swift4.2

I am working on app that needs facebook to login. In other means we are using facebook authentication in our app along with in app login screen.

So now at very first, I was able to login using my facebook account. When i first tried it, I have to provide both user name and my password to get login using my facebook account credentials.

Now after that I want to logOut from facebook account whenever user hit Logout button from our app. Here is what I am doing

```
        AccessToken.current = nil
        Profile.current = nil
        LoginManager().logOut()
```

but it is not actually working. When I press again to login back, now I never see that screen where I gave facebook account credentials. its mean LogOut() function is not working.

Please help me this is weird behavior from facebook sdk